# entity framework client connection details versus connection details in EF library?

Tags: entity-framework, entity, connection-string

I have an EF project which has embedded connection details.

Then when I use this project from a client library I get told to copy the config file across, which includes the connection details.

What are the rules re which connection string would be used here?  i.e. does the database connection string in the client project override any connection strings in the EF library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection strings in the library project are never used, they aren't in the bin folder with your final executable.  Only the connections strings you copy over to the application or web config files (as appropriate) are used.

But don't copy the whole config file over - you want just the connection strings.